# How to apply CSS to the root of a Vue 3 component?

Tags: css, vuejs3

I am moving Vue 2 source over to Vue 3 (beta), and came across this:

```
<template>
  <section id="this">   <!-- how to eliminate this? -->
    <div>
      YOU ARE AT HOME 
    </div>

    <h2>Hi <span>{{ uid }}</span></h2>

    <!-- List the projects we have access to -->
    <div id="grid-container-projects">
      <ProjectTile :project="null" />
      <ProjectTile v-for="p in projectsSorted" :key="p.key" :project="p" />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<style scoped>
  #this {
    text-align: center;
  }
  ...
```

The details don't matter. Applying the `text-align: center` to the `#this` node is what I'd like to achieve, but without the `#this` node.

Is this possible, or reasonable? :)

I tried the following:

```
<template>   <-- Vue 3 (beta) -->
  <div>
    YOU ARE AT HOME 
  </div>
 ...
</template>

<style scoped>
  * { 
    text-align: center
  }
  ...
```

This does the wished layout, but causes a stack overflow in the browser. That may of course be just a Vue 3 betaism. (3.0.0-beta.4)

How would you proceed? Leave the `section` as is, or get rid of it, somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I will go with the `section` because there you add an id in the div tag to uniquely centralize that element.

while in the second option you will generally centralize all the component elements